# How to specify package versions when deploying Shiny app to Shinyio

Tags: r, shiny

I have the development version of `data.table` (version 1.9.7) installed on my machine.  I built a Shiny app which works with 1.9.6 *and* 1.9.7, but in order for me to deploy my app to shinyio I have to uninstall 1.9.7 and reinstall 1.9.6 (before reinstalling 1.9.7 again) otherwise I get an error.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Did you read [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505627/error-when-trying-to-deploy-to-shinyapps-io-application-depends-on-package-pac)? You can try to declare the package dependencies with @Yihui's method.

Comment: I did not find that.  Thanks

Comment: It's unclear to me how Yihui's method would translate to a regular use case. Instead of e.g. `library(data.table)` would I use `do.call(library, list('data.table'))`? How would this guarantee a specific version of the package to be loaded?