# ERROR: no library trees found in 'lib.loc' when deploying Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I got this error when I tried to deploy my App using https://www.shinyapps.io/.

ERROR: no library trees found in 'lib.loc'

Any idea why? I found several threads about it but the explanation are not very clear to me.

These are the locations of my packages:

```
library("plyr", lib.loc="C:/Users/Ktanizar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4")

library("cluster", lib.loc="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/library")

library("xlsx", lib.loc="C:/Users/Ktanizar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4")

library("seriation", lib.loc="C:/Users/Ktanizar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4")

library("data.tree", lib.loc="C:/Users/Ktanizar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4")

library("DT", lib.loc="C:/Users/Ktanizar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4")

library("shinythemes", lib.loc="C:/Users/Ktanizar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4")

library("clipr", lib.loc="C:/Users/Ktanizar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4")
```

Here is the result when I run .libPaths()
[1] 
"C:/Users/KTanizar/Documents/R/win-library/3.4" 
    "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/library"

Here is the path of rsconnect

rsconnect::deployApp('C:/Users/Ketty Noonan/Desktop/Innovation Projects/0 Market Structure/5 Innovation/1 R scripts and notes/R_Shiny/2 Deploy')

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when trying to deploy to shinyapps.io: Application depends on package "package" but it is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505627/error-when-trying-to-deploy-to-shinyapps-io-application-depends-on-package-pac)

Comment: Thanks. It works now when I added .... do.call(library, list(package = c("plyr", "cluster", "xlsx", "seriation", "data.tree", "DT", "shinythemes", "clipr"), character.only = TRUE)).  However, I now got an error message "**ERROR: could not find function "shinytheme"**. Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

It works now with the following codes:

```
if(!require("plyr"))
  install.packages("plyr")
if(!require("cluster"))
  install.packages("cluster")
if(!require("xlsx"))
  install.packages("xlsx")
if(!require("seriation"))
  install.packages("seriation")
if(!require("data.tree"))
  install.packages("data.tree")
if(!require("DT"))
  install.packages("DT")
if(!require("shinythemes"))
  install.packages("shinythemes")
if(!require("clipr"))
  install.packages("clipr")
```

and when I changed the following code

```
fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
```

from the following

```
fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("spacelab"),
```

Hope this helps someone and thank you, Jarko.